# What wrong I am doing in IEnumerable(C#3.0)

Tags: linq, c#-3.0, anonymous-types

If I write

```
var v = (from r in stock.ReplacementLog
                                             select new 
                                             {
                                                 AssetId = stock.AssetId,
                                                 Date = stock.ReferDate,
                                                 FactType = r.Key,
                                                 Value = r.Value
                                             });
```

It is working fine...

But if I do

```
IEnumerable<StockAsset> v = (from r in stock.ReplacementLog
 select new  {
 AssetId = stock.AssetId,
Date = stock.ReferDate,
FactType = r.Key,
Value = r.Value });
```

I am getting error:

**Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)**

Then I did

```
IEnumerable<StockAsset> v = 
(
from r in stock.ReplacementLog
select new
{
AssetId = stock.AssetId,
Date = stock.ReferDate,
FactType = r.Key,
Value = r.Value
}).ToList<StockAsset>();
```

With the following bunch of errors:

**Error 1   Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'**

**Error 2   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments**

Then I tried with

```
IEnumerable<StockAsset> v1 = 
(from r in stock.ReplacementLog
select new StockAsset 
{
AssetId = stock.AssetId,
ReferDate= stock.ReferDate,
FactType = r.Key,
Value = r.Value
});
```

with the errors:
    **Error 1
    'StockAsset' does not contain a definition for 'FactType'**

```
**Error 2
'StockAsset' does not contain a definition for Value'**
```

The StockAsset Class is as under

```
public class StockAsset
{
        public int AssetId { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReferDate {get;set;}        
        public Dictionary<EnumFactorType, double> ReplacementLog { get; set; }   
}
```

Need help.

Using C#3.0

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```
select new  {
 AssetId = stock.AssetId,
 Date = stock.ReferDate,
 FactType = r.Key,
 Value = r.Value }
```

You actually generate an anonymous type. You can't cast this anonymous type to a declared type.

If you want to create an object of the class you should do

```
 select new StockAsset
 {
     AssetId = ..., // Maybe stock.AssetId
     ReferDate = ..., // Maybe stock.ReferDate
     ReplacementLog = ... // Maybe new Dictionary<string, short> { {r.Key, r.Value} };
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately the StockAsset class doesn't have Date, FactType or Value properties, so that would still give an error.

Comment: Actually yes... So how to overcome that

Comment: Error 1 
'StockAsset' does not contain a definition for 'Date' 

Error 2
'StockAsset' does not contain a definition for 'FactType'

Error 3
'StockAsset' does not contain a definition for Value'

Comment: @Newbie, you should decide how do you want to create the values for the properties of StockAsset.

Comment: Sir, The output I have generated using the VAR(as described in the question)

Comment: If I understood, you mean
IEnumerable<StockAsset> v1 = 
(from r in stock.ReplacementLog
select new StockAsset 
{
AssetId = stock.AssetId,
Date = stock.ReferDate,
ReplacementLog = r
}); 

and the error:

Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair< EnumFactorType,double>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary< EnumFactorType,double>

Comment: @Newbie, look at the comments I've added.

Comment: ReplacementLog = new Dictionary<EnumFactorType,double>(new[]{r})
error
Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair< EnumFactorType,double>[]' to 'int'

Comment: @Newbie, I've fixed the comment.

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
select new { property = value }
```

you're creating an instance of a new *anonymous* type, whereas it looks like you want to actually be creating `StockAsset`s, so you want

```
select new StockAsset { property = value }
```

Comment: I am getting error:

Error 1 
'StockAsset' does not contain a definition for 'Date'
Error 2
'StockAsset' does not contain a definition for 'FactType'
Error 3
'StockAsset' does not contain a definition for Value'

when I am doing

IEnumerable<StockAsset> v1 = 
(from r in stock.ReplacementLog
select new StockAsset 
{
AssetId = stock.AssetId,
Date = stock.ReferDate,
FactType = r.Key,
Value = r.Value
});

Comment: StockAsset doesn't have a property named Value. Are you really trying to create a StockAsset object, and if so, what is the Value supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you're trying to create a new StockAsset for each entry in another StockAsset's ReplacementLog. This new StockAsset is going to have a single entry in its ReplacementLog. Is this correct? If so, you could create a new constructor on StockAsset:

```
public StockAsset(int assetId, DateTime referDate, 
                  EnumFactorType factorType, double value)
{
    AssetId = assetId;
    ReferDate = referDate;
    ReplacementLog = new Dictionary<EnumFactorType, double>();
    ReplacementLog[factorType] = value;
}
```

And then call that constructor inside of your LINQ.

```
IEnumerable<StockAsset> v = (from r in stock.ReplacementLog
    select new StockAsset(stock.AssetId, stock.ReferDate, r.Key, r.Value));
```